# Proof there exists two straight lines with a certain property

Tags: geometry

[image]

This is a question from one of my maths past papers. I understand that the answers would be yes, yes, no for each part of the question but I don't understand how to prove.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than votes to close or downvotes if you edit the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Hint: for the first two, to "prove" the answer is "yes" you need only give an example. Lines parallel to the coordinate axes will do.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that the answer to (iii) is no, consider that otherwise you would have more than one plane passing through three non-aligned points, and that contradicts an axiom of geometry.